# Python weave compile error

Tags: python, weave

I'm new to weave and I have no clue what is causing this error.  The error happens on other code examples too so it's not the specific code.  I'm using windows 7 and python 2.7.  Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
>>> from scipy import weave
>>> a = 1
>>> weave.inline('printf("%d\\n",a);',['a'])

No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Looking for python27.dll
Looking for python27.dll


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    weave.inline('printf("%d\\n",a);',['a'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 366, in inline
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 496, in compile_function
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\scipy\weave\ext_tools.py", line 373, in compile
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\scipy\weave\build_tools.py", line 279, in build_extension
    setup(name=module_name, ext_modules=[ext],verbose=verb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 166, in setup
    raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
CompileError: error: Command "g++ -m64 -g -shared c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\scipy-owner-tbcany\python27_intermediate\compiler_e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb924\Release\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\owner\python27_compiled\sc_cb1945ea063627b5855c13eafebb07042.o c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\scipy-owner-tbcany\python27_intermediate\compiler_e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb924\Release\python27\lib\scipy\weave\scxx\weave_imp.o -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\owner\python27_compiled\sc_cb1945ea063627b5855c13eafebb07042.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

weave.test() didn't find any errors but it only ran 146 tests and the documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html says that it should have ran 180.

```
>>> weave.test()
Running unit tests for scipy.weave
NumPy version 1.9.1
NumPy is installed in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy
SciPy version 0.15.1
SciPy is installed in C:\Python27\lib\scipy
Python version 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
nose version 1.3.7
..................................S.SSS....SSSSSS.................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 146 tests in 3.439s

OK (SKIP=10)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=146 errors=0 failures=0>
```

Comment: Seems g++ command is not found. Do you have gcc installed? If yes, then check your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

...quite some time ago I ran into issues with compiling `weave` code. The problem was probably caused by mixing (Visual Studio) precompiled Python with MinGW-compiled `weave` code.

Back then, I was using the MinGW64 compiler (MinGW32 worked as well) and developed a three step workaround.

1) In the `<pythondir>\libs` directory, delete the MSVCR runtime library file, it should be named something like `libmsvcr100.a` or `libmsvcr100d.a` (or with `90` or any other version number in it). Along with it delete any file in the folder that has the same creation date (first attempt of using weave).

2) in the (probably not yet created) file `<pythondir>\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` and also `<pythondir>\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\distutils.cfg` I included the compiler definition

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

Maybe you'd need to adjust that to your type of compiler.

3) In `<pythondir>\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py` there comes the real "hack" at around line #329:

in the function implementation of `build_msvcr_libaray(debug=False)` just hardcode `return False` as the first line of code.

Now retry your `weave` code...

Comment: Note: also for MinGW64 you need to set "mingw32" as the compiler definition. It just tells distutils how to invoke the compiler command...